# Fetching 4 Images With Different Sizes

Tags: php, css, mysql

Good Day, I want to display all images but it seems hard to me fetch it with different sizes if my table is per row. Please take a look on the image. 
You can see that the all images are inside the single row. So I used array to display it and call its column name to separate the width and height of every individual. How can I fetch it in rows form. 
For example:
row1 : where image_one is stored
row2 : where image_two is stored
row3 : where image_three is stored
row4 : where image_four is stored

so basically it has primary key on it. 
and heres the css for it:
which was took here in stack by SEAN

```html
 img {
  height: 200px; // set a standard height
  padding-bottom: 5px; // add a space between the img rows
}
.image-one-frame, .image-four-frame {
  width: 66%; // make one and four 2/3 the width
}
.image-two-frame, .image-three-frame {
  width: 33%; // make two and three 1/3 the width
}
.image-one-frame, .image-three-frame {
  float: left; // make one and three float left
}
 .image-two-frame, .image-four-frame {
  float: right; // make two and four float right
}
```

```
 $viewquery= mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * from sales");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($viewquery)) {



  echo'   <div class="div-frame-five">';

  echo'     <img src="images/'.$row["image_one"].'"   alt=""   class="image- 
  one-frame">';
  echo'     <img src="images/'.$row["image_two"].'"   alt=""   class="image- 
  two-frame">';
  echo'     <img src="images/'.$row["image_three"].'" alt=""   class="image- 
  three-frame">';
  echo'     <img src="images/'.$row["image_four"].'" alt=""   class="image- 
  four-frame">';
  echo' </div>';
```

}

THIS IS TABLE IN THE DB
[Image Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnLWY.png)